# Pydev: jump past closing parenthesis with <Tab>

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Eclipse's Java editor has this wonderful feature: if you press Tab before a closing parenthesis, it will jump past the parenthesis instead of inserting an actual tab. For example:

type in 'myfunc'

```
myfunc<cursor>
```

type '(' ... eclipse puts the ')' for you.

```
myfunc(<cursor>)
```

type in the args

```
myfunc(arg1, arg2<cursor>)
```

then hit Tab

```
myfunc(arg1, arg2)<cursor>
```

I have become very fond of this behavior, and prefer it to typing in the ')' which most editors do absorb. Is there a way to configure **PyDev** to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Preferences** > **PyDev** > **Editor** > **Typing**
and check "*Enable link on automatic parenthesis or literals closing*".